# Handling WebSocket Stream Disconnection and SourceBuffer Error in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sockets, websocket

I am developing an Electron app that allows users to stream video content using WebSockets. I have successfully implemented the streaming functionality, including starting and stopping streams, calculating statistics, and displaying the stream in a modal (on Vue APP). However, I am encountering a couple of issues that I need help resolving.

When the stream starts and ends, the socket ID is also stored in the database by an API, which I am also displaying on the Vue app.

Handling Stream on Page Refresh:
How can I handle this scenario when the page is refreshed? There is no streaming when the page was refreshed, but I am getting a continuous buffer array through the socket.

SourceBuffer Error when Opening Modal:
When attempting to open the modal to view the stream, I encounter the following error:

```
Error: Failed to read the 'buffered' property from 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
```

Additionally, I get a "**Failed to load because no supported source was found**" DOMException. What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? I suspect it may be related to the state of the MediaSource and SourceBuffer, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot and fix it.

```
            this.socket.on("start-streaming", async (data) => {
                this.streaming_client_id = data.id;
               
               // Initialize MediaSource here if not initialized
                if(this.is_stream_modal_open)
                {
                    this.initMediaSource();
                }
            });

            this.socket.on('video-frame', (data) => {
                console.log('video-frame', data);
                if(! this.media_source) return;


                //Calculation FPS and other details
               ...............

                const arrayU8 = new Uint8Array(data);

               
                if (this.media_source.readyState === 'open') {
                    this.media_source.sourceBuffers[0].appendBuffer(arrayU8);
                } else {
                    console.log('Media source is not in open state: ',  this.media_source.readyState);
                }
            });

            this.socket.on("stop-streaming", (data) => {
               

                if(this.remote_video)
                {
                    this.remote_video.pause();
                    this.remote_video.src = '';
                }
                this.streaming_client_id = null;
                this.media_source = null;
                this.stats = {
                    data_transferred: 0,
                    fps: 0,
                    network_speed: 0,
                    resolution: {
                        width: 0,
                        height: 0
                    }
                }
            });

        },

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        initMediaSource()
        {
            if (!this.media_source) {

                this.media_source = new MediaSource();
                this.media_source.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
                    console.log('MediaSource sourceopen');
                    const sourceBuffer = this.media_source.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8"');
                    console.log('SourceBuffer created', sourceBuffer);

                    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => {
                        console.log('SourceBuffer updateend');
                        if (this.remote_video.paused) {
                            this.remote_video.play();
                        }
                    });

                    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
                        console.error('SourceBuffer error:', event);
                    });
                });

                if(this.remote_video)
                {
                    this.remote_video.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.media_source);
                }
            } else {
                console.log('MediaSource already exists');
                this.remote_video.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.media_source); 

            }
        },
```